cloud run function to flatten document and sync with Meilisearch
I have a collection movies with a subcollection subtitles with only one document in the subcollection.
I added a cloud run function that triggers on changes to the movies collection to sync data to Meilisearch. This works fine.
One field in movies is subtitlesId which is the document number of the document in the subcollection. I am trying to extract that document and add it to the movies document before syncing to Meilisearch but that is failing. I am using node.js - here's my code. The service account the secret is for has proper permissions.
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const axios = require("axios");
const {SecretManagerServiceClient} = require('@google-cloud/secret-manager');
const protobuf = require("protobufjs");
const functions = require("@google-cloud/functions-framework");


const GCLOUD_PROJECT = process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT;
const SECRET_NAME= process.env.NO_ENV_SE;
const client = new SecretManagerServiceClient();


async function getServiceAccountKey() {
  if (!SECRET_NAME) {
    throw new Error("The environment variable for the secret full path is not set.");
  }

  try {
    let payload = SECRET_NAME;

    if (!payload) {
      throw new Error("Secret payload is missing or empty.");
    }
    const serviceAccount = JSON.parse(payload);

    if (!serviceAccount.private_key || !serviceAccount.client_email) {
      throw new Error("Invalid service account JSON: Missing required fields.");
    }

    return serviceAccount;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching or parsing secret:", error);
    throw error;
  }
}

async function initializeFirebaseAdmin() {
  try {
    const serviceAccount = await getServiceAccountKey();
    admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    });

    console.log("Firebase Admin initialized successfully.");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Failed to initialize Firebase Admin:", error);
    throw error;
  }
}

// Call the initialization
initializeFirebaseAdmin().catch((err) => {
  console.error("Initialization failed:", err);
});

// Replace with your Meilisearch host and API key
const MEILISEARCH_HOST = "https://....”;
const MEILISEARCH_API_KEY = “API KEY HERE”;


let DocumentEventData;

async function loadProtobufSchema() {
  if (!DocumentEventData) {
    const root = await protobuf.load("google/protobuf/data.proto");
    DocumentEventData = root.lookupType("google.events.cloud.firestore.v1.DocumentEventData");
  }
}

async function fetchTranscriptions(moviesDocId, subtitleId) {
  try {
    
    const subtitlePath = `movies/${moviesDocId}/subtitles/${subtitleId}`;

    const subDocRef = admin.firestore().doc(subtitlePath);

     // Await Firestore query
    const subDoc = await subDocRef.get();

    if (! subDoc.exists) {
      console.error(`Transcription document not found: ${subtitlePath}`);
      return [];
    }
      const subData = subDoc.data();
    if (! subData || !Array.isArray(subData.subtitle)) {
      console.warn("No valid subs data found in document:", subData);
      return [];
    }

    return subData.subtitle.map((segment, index) => ({
      id: `${index}`,
      startTime: segment.startTime,
      endTime: segment.endTime,
      text: segment.text,
    }));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching sub document:", error.message);
    console.error("Stack trace:", error.stack);
    return [];
  }
}



functions.cloudEvent("syncToMeilisearchMediaPOST", async (cloudEvent) => {
  console.log("Event received:", {
    docPath: cloudEvent.subject,
    docId: cloudEvent.subject.split("/").pop(),
  });

  await loadProtobufSchema();

  // Decode the raw Protobuf payload
  let eventData;
  try {
    eventData = DocumentEventData.decode(cloudEvent.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error decoding Protobuf eventData:", error.message);
    return;
  }

  // Extract document path and ID
  const docPath = cloudEvent.subject;
  const docId = docPath.split("/").pop();

  // Determine event type (create, update, delete)
  const oldValue = eventData.oldValue || null;
  const value = eventData.value || null;
try {
  if (value) {
    console.log(`CREATE Document in movies/${docId}:`, value.fields);
    const documentData = mapFirestoreDocument(value.fields, docId);
    console.log(`Final Meilisearch document on CREATE:`, JSON.stringify(documentData, null, 2)); // Log the document being sent to Meilisearch
    
    if (documentData.subtitleId) {
      const subtitles = await fetchTranscriptions(docId, documentData. subtitleId);

    
      if (subtitles && subtitles.length > 0) {
        documentData. subtitles = subtitles;
      }
    }
  
    console.log(`Final Meilisearch document with subtitles:`, JSON.stringify(documentData, null, 2));

    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        `${MEILISEARCH_HOST}/indexes/movies/documents`,
        documentData,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${MEILISEARCH_API_KEY}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        }
      );
      console.log("CREATE Document successfully synced to Meilisearch:", response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("CREATE Error syncing document to Meilisearch:", error.message);
    }
  } ....
  });


function mapFirestoreDocument(fields, docId, parentKey = '') {
  const document = { id: docId };
  
  // Define fields to exclude from syncing
  const exclusionList = [... EXCLUDED HERE....];

  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(fields)) {
    const fieldPath = parentKey ? `${parentKey}.${key}` : key;

    if (exclusionList.includes(key)) {
      console.log(`Excluding field: ${key}`);
      continue;
    }

    console.log(`Processing field: ${key} =>`, JSON.stringify(value, null, 2));

    try {
      // Handle different Firestore field types
      if (value.timestampValue) {
        // Convert Firestore timestamp to ISO string
        const seconds = parseInt(value.timestampValue.seconds, 10);
        const nanos = value.timestampValue.nanos ? value.timestampValue.nanos / 1e6 : 0; // Convert nanos to milliseconds
        const timestamp = new Date(seconds * 1000 + nanos);
        document[key] = timestamp.toISOString();
        console.log(`Assigned timestampValue for ${key}:`, document[key]);
      }
      else if (value.mapValue) {
        // Recursively process nested maps
        document[key] = mapFirestoreDocument(value.mapValue.fields || {}, docId, key);
        console.log(`Assigned mapValue for ${key}:`, document[key]);
      }
      else if (value.arrayValue) {
        // Process arrays with proper type handling for each element
        document[key] = (value.arrayValue.values || []).map((v) => {
          if (v.stringValue !== undefined) return v.stringValue;
          if (v.integerValue !== undefined) return parseInt(v.integerValue, 10);
          if (v.doubleValue !== undefined) return parseFloat(v.doubleValue);
          if (v.booleanValue !== undefined) return v.booleanValue;
          if (v.mapValue !== undefined) return mapFirestoreDocument(v.mapValue.fields || {}, docId, key);
          if (v.timestampValue !== undefined) {
            const seconds = parseInt(v.timestampValue.seconds, 10);
            const nanos = v.timestampValue.nanos ? v.timestampValue.nanos / 1e6 : 0;
            return new Date(seconds * 1000 + nanos).toISOString();
          }
          console.warn(`Unhandled array element type for key "${key}":`, JSON.stringify(v, null, 2));
          return null;
        }).filter(item => item !== null);
        console.log(`Assigned arrayValue for ${key}:`, document[key]);
      }
      else if (value.stringValue !== undefined) {
        document[key] = value.stringValue;
        console.log(`Assigned stringValue for ${key}:`, document[key]);
      }
      else if (value.integerValue !== undefined) {
        document[key] = parseInt(value.integerValue, 10);
        console.log(`Assigned integerValue for ${key}:`, document[key]);
      }
      else if (value.doubleValue !== undefined) {
        document[key] = parseFloat(value.doubleValue);
        console.log(`Assigned doubleValue for ${key}:`, document[key]);
      }
      else if (value.booleanValue !== undefined) {
        document[key] = value.booleanValue;
        console.log(`Assigned booleanValue for ${key}:`, document[key]);
      }
      else {
        console.warn(`Unhandled Firestore field type for key "${key}"`, JSON.stringify(value, null, 2));
        document[key] = null;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Error processing field "${key}":`, error.message);
      document[key] = null;
    }
  }

  console.log(`Final mapped document for ${parentKey || 'root'}:`, JSON.stringify(document, null, 2));
  return document;
}

There may be some typos in the parameter names since I changed those from the original ones - however they do match in the actual function.
Any help would be appreciated.
